# Android. Имитация входящего вызова

Tags: java, android

может это уже обсуждалось, но не знаю даже как в поиске вбить правильно... поверхностный осмотр по ключевым словам ничего путного не выдал. 
вопрос вот в чем. нужно программно осуществить имитацию входящего вызова (с какого номера - не важно, хоть вообще без номера). возможно ли это на нерутованных девайсах?

Comment: Уточните пожалуйста цель данного. Вы хотите сделать свою программу, которая будет имитировать входящие вызовы? Или просто необходима готовая для данных целей?

Answer (score 2):

На эмуляторе

> $ telnet localhost 5554 
>   $ gsm call 123456789

Comment: а можно ли как то это дело вызвать программно из приложения?

Comment: Маловероятно, судя http://stackoverflow.com/a/6337691/5892568 это не  очень возможно. Т.е. все эти приложения просто полностью повторяют внешний вид реальных, благо можно выдрать UI из исходников платформы.

Answer (score 0):

Вбейте "Fake Call" в Play Маркете и выбирайте.
Еще у Genymotion есть такая функция, но она доступна в платной версии.

Comment: мне нужна именно функция на java для своего проекта